# MySQL trigger query from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im running the following query from my PhpMyadmin sql tab

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger 
AFTER INSERT ON tbl_table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO tbl_table2 (id,name) values (NEW.id,NEW.name); 
END
```

But everytime I'm getting this error msg:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Im using MySQL client version: 5.1.37,PHPMyadmim Version information: 3.2.2.1deb1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

> When you want to use `SET NEW.col_name = value` in your trigger, please
>   note that you **CANNOT use this with the AFTER the action**, and must use
>   it **BEFORE** the action.

So probably you should try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tbl_table2 (id,name) values (NEW.id,NEW.name); 
END
```

**EDITED:**  I tried this and it's working in MySQL

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS testTrigger;
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO tbl_table2 VALUES (NEW.id,NEW.name);
END;
```

Then tried `INSERT INTO test1 SELECT 5,'pois';` and trigger worked!!